# CSS : Object Cover doesn't center an image

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a thumbnail grid, that will be used mainly on mobile.

The image size is unknown : it comes from an Input, and size is dependant of the camera on the mobile phone. *So I don't know in advance if a photo will be  landscape or portrait*. And thus the styling for both thumbnails should be identical.

For a landscape image, I want it to be shown the full height and horizontally centered.
For a Portrait image I want to show the full width of the image and vertically centered.

```
LANDSCAPE IMAGE          PORTRAIT IMAGE
                            +++++++
                            +     +
                            +     +
++++++=======++++++         =======
+     =======     +         =======
+     =======     +         =======
+     =======     +         =======
+     =======     +         =======
++++++=======++++++         =======
                            +     +
                            +     +
                            +++++++

== = actual thumbnail = part of the full image that will be shown
+ = full image size
```

I guess `object-fit: cover;` would be best fit.

This works for the  landscape image (see codepen : The men on the right is not showw, which is expected)

Unfortunately this doesn't work for the portrait image.  The width is correctly scaled to the width of the thumb, but the image is not vertically centered. (see codepen : the top of the building is still visible while the man in front disappeared. What I expected is the top of the building no longer visible, and  the head if the man completely visible. I could fix this with a translate, but then the same code won't work with the portrait.

See codepen, using Tailwind
https://codepen.io/pasdut/pen/MWbzvzX

Update : I don't know in advance if an image wille be portrait or landscape

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you give the the portrait image `height: 100%` it will horizontally and vertically center the image in it's container paired with `object-fit: cover`. You just need to add the `h-full` tailwind class to the thumbnail #2 `<img>` element for it to have `height: 100%`.

```
<img class="object-cover min-w-full min-h-full h-full" 
  src="https://dummyimage.com/400x900/472647/ffff00&text=portrait+image">
```

[image: Image thumbnail vertically/horizontally centered]

Comment: HI Tanner, Thanks for your answer. This seems to be working for the landscape image too. I've added real images to working codepen https://codepen.io/pasdut/pen/GRNwXzq?editors=1010

Comment: Although this answer is correct this doesn't always work with Chrome. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62825499/is-object-fit-breaking-some-image-aspect-ratios-in-chrome.  Will be fixed in chrome 89 ?

Comment: @Pasduti Yeah I've read about the `object-fit` browser bug in Chromium. There's not much we can do about it until the Chrome team fixes the bug.

Answer (score 1):

I am not using Tailwind so I just gonna give you the code that works.

```
.portrait {
    height: 100% !important;
    min-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

In your second image remove whatever in there and use the "portrait" class. It's actually worked for the first image also if it's the effect you want.

Comment: HI Co Pham. Thanks for the answer.  This seems to pull the trick : see https://codepen.io/pasdut/pen/RwoqYQN